# How to calculate total 6 months in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I try this SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    custodycd,
    SUM(mramt) mramt_6_month,
    txdate,
    CASE    
        WHEN LAG(mramt, 6) OVER (ORDER BY txdate) IS NOT NULL
            THEN SUM(mramt) OVER (ORDER BY txdate ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS mramt_6_month_1
FROM
    (SELECT
         MAX(mramt) mramt,
         t.afacctno,
         t.custodycd,
         t.txdate 
     FROM
         tbl_mr3007_log t 
     WHERE
         txdate >= '30/nov/2020' 
         AND mramt <> 0 
     GROUP BY
         t.afacctno,
         t.txdate,
         t.custodycd) 
GROUP BY
    custodycd,
    txdate 
ORDER BY
    txdate
```

and I get an error:

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please specify what are you trying to achieve with the query, and the expected result? Please, check  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to ask a correct question.

Comment: Condition `WHERE txdate >= '30/nov/2020'` seems to be **very** bad. If you really store the date values like this string, the result will be crap!

Comment: the reason for the error is due to the existence of `LAG(mramt, 6)` . Since `mramt` column is neither kept in the GROUP BY list, nor an aggregation function is applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems pretty clear.  However, what you want to do is not clear.

I am guessing that for each `custodycd` you have multiple rows by date.  Starting at the seventh row, you want the sum of the previous six rows.

If so, then the code looks like:

```
(CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custodycd ORDER BY txdate) > 6
      THEN SUM(SUM(mramt)) OVER (PARTITION BY custodycd
                                 ORDER BY txdate
                                 ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                                )
 END) AS mramt_6_month_1
```